# jQuery check if div has matching text and then copy style

Tags: jquery, styles, contains

I need to check if two divs contain the same text and if they do I then need to copy the style of one and apply it to another, this is the set up;

```
 <div class="coursediv">   <label>Melbourne</label></div>
 <div class="coursediv">    <label>Sydney</label></div>
 <div class="coursediv">    <label>Darwin</label></div>
 <div class="coursediv">    <label>Brisbane</label></div>
 <div class="coursediv">    <label>Townsville</label></div>



 <div class="infobox">
 <p>Melbourne</p></div>
 <div class="infobox">
 <p>Sydney</p></div>
 <div class="infobox">
 <p>Darwin</p></div>
 <div class="infobox">
 <p>Brisbane</p></div>
 <div class="infobox">
 <p>Townsville</p></div>
```

The styles use nth of type, so not sure if this is possible, styles and set up can be seen here 
http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/7bvuzsru/1/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why are you using `!important`?

Comment: only some code i found from another example that could see if the text didn't match and apply a style, but I think its the wrong starting point for what I need

Comment: I am using !important; because of the rest of the set up, but I can remove that and work around it if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your div's using [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$(".infobox").each(function(i,v){
   var $info = $(this);

   $(".coursediv").each(function(i,v){
       var $course = $(this);

       if($info.text()==$course.text()){
          $info.addClass( $course.attr('class') );
       }
   });
});
```

Should be enough to infer from.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to use this? and wouldn't that apply the same background color to all elements?

Comment: If you don't know how to use jQuery, why don't you try to learn it from http://www.jQuery.com like everyone else? :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am trying (slowly), but this specific problem needs a quick fix for an angry boss

Comment: Could you at least explain the logic? wouldn't that add the same class to all elements?

Comment: Yes, it adds the `same` class to both elements that match text inside.  How did you get a job doing jQuery when you don't know it, is what I'd like to know

Comment: I understood the logic of your suggestion, its just that the fact that it doesn't relate to my question at all is what confused me.

Comment: Well you are the one that asked *I need to check if two divs contain the same text and if they do I then need to copy the style of one and apply it to another* Right?

Comment: I gave you a completely valid answer for you to infer from. If you expect someone to write this application for you, I have some bad news.